# Order a list of string by quantity

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of string that i want to order by quantity. The List contain a list of Order-CreationDate with datetime values. I'm converting this values to strings as as i will need that for later.

My current output is a list of CreationDate that looks like this.

```
2014-04-05
2014-04-05
2014-04-05
2014-04-05
2014-04-06
2014-04-06
2014-04-06
...
```

I get a list of dates as expected but i want to group number of dates by the date. This mean i need another variable with number of total orders. Ive tried creating a new variable, using a for loop and linq queries but not getting the results I want.

How can I get number of orders by `CreationDate`? I need to count total number of orders by `CreationDate` but I can't find a way to do this.

The expected output would be:

```
2014-04-05 4 - representing 4 orders that date
2014-04-06 3 - representing 3 orders that date.
```

This what my code looks like:

```
List<string> TotalOrdersPaid = new List<string>();

foreach (var order in orders)
{
    if (order.PaymentStatus == PaymentStatus.Paid)
    {
        string Created = order.CreatedOnUtc.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        order.CreatedOnUtc = DateTime.ParseExact(Created, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        TotalOrdersPaid.Add(Created);
    }
}
```

Eg `TotalOrdersPaid` should contain a list with number of orders by `CreationDate`.

What is a good way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check if this works?

`var grouppedDate = TotalOrdersPaid.GroupBy(x => x.Created);`

Comment: Tried pretty much the same thing: orders.OrderBy(x => order.CreatedOnUtc); Dosn't work or i'm doing it wrong. I get a list but nut number of orders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To group the orders by date, take following LinQ lambda expression:

```
var grouped = orders.Where(o => o.PaymentStatus == PaymentStatus.Paid)
                    .GroupBy(g => g.CreatedOnUtc);
```

Now, all paid orders are grouped by date. To count the orders per date, select the key which is the date, and the `Count()` will count all orders for that date.

```
var counted = grouped.Select(s => new { Date = s.Key, Count = s.Count() });
```

**Edit:**

In one statement:

```
var result = orders.Where(o => o.PaymentStatus == PaymentStatus.Paid)
                   .GroupBy(g => g.CreatedOnUtc)
                   .Select(s => new { Date = s.Key, Count = s.Count() });
```

Based on your list of dates, the output will look like:

`Date         Count
 5/04/2014       4 
 6/04/2014       3`

**Update:**

If you want to put more properties in the anonymous type that will be returned from the `Select()` method, sumply just add them. If, for example, you want the date, the count *and* the list of orders for that date, use following line of code:

```
var result = orders.Where(o => o.PaymentStatus == PaymentStatus.Paid)
                   .GroupBy(g => g.CreatedOnUtc)
                   .Select(s => new
                   {
                       Date = s.Key,
                       Count = s.Count(),
                       Items = s.ToList()
                   });
```

Now you can do following:

```
foreach(var orderGroup in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Number of orders for {0}: {1}", orderGroup.Date, orderGroup.Count));

    foreach(var order in orderGroup.Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(order.Name);
    }
}
```

This will loop over all grouped items and display a sentence like:

> Number of orders for 5/04/2014: 4

And then it will display the name of each order for that date (if your order has a property `Name`). Hope this clears everything out.

Comment: This is great and very informative. Archiveing that with pretty much no code at all, Linq sure is very handy. Will def have this in mind in the future. Thank you!

Comment: If i may ask, could i querry more values to the list or am i restricted to one key and value? Also result returns a list of AnonymousType1, will i be able to access Date or Count and return them?

Answer (score 5):

basically, you just need a group by and and ordering.

```
var result = orders//add any where clause needed
             .GroupBy(m => m)
             .Select(m => new {
                cnt = m.Count(),
                date = m.Key
             })
             .OrderByDescending(m => m.cnt);
```

Of course, you can add any DateTime.Parse / ParseExact in the Select, and / or project to a corresponding class.